# How distribute SQL results horizontally?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server like this(all columns are numerics):

```
Id1 | Id2 | Number | Qty
----+-----+--------+-------
  1 |  1  | 100001 | 100
  1 |  2  | 100002 | 110
  1 |  3  | 100003 | 120
  2 |  1  | 100004 | 130
  2 |  2  | 100005 | 200
  2 |  3  | 100006 | 300
  2 |  4  | 100007 | 400
```

and i want the result distributed in 2 more columns, like this (without Id's):

```
 Number1 | Qty1  | Number2 | Qty2  | Number3 | Qty3 
 --------+-------|---------|-------|---------|------
  100001 | 100   | 100002  | 110   | 100003  | 120
  100004 | 130   | 100005  | 200   | 100006  | 300
  100007 | 400   |  null   | null  |  null   | null
```

Is it possible?
Thanks.

Comment: I think it is different, I don't want to "rotate" the result, i want to distribute the results n times.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN id2 = 1 THEN number ELSE '' END AS 'Number1',
CASE WHEN id2 = 1 THEN Qty ELSE '' END AS 'Qty1',
CASE WHEN id2 = 2 THEN number ELSE '' END AS 'Number2',
CASE WHEN id2 = 2 THEN Qty ELSE '' END AS 'Qty2',
CASE WHEN id2 = 3 THEN number ELSE '' END AS 'Number3',
CASE WHEN id2 = 3 THEN Qty ELSE '' END AS 'Qty3'
FROM tablename
```

Comment: Thanks. But not pratical, i can have 50 rows (id2)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind is a recursive CTE. that will allow you to play with the n values in Id2. Are you sure the Id2 value for your last row is correct with a value of 4?

Answer (score 0):

what do you need is a PIVOT. Here is the link :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

is this useful.?

```
    DECLARE @T AS TABLE
        (
            id1 INT, 
            id2 int ,
            Number INT,
            Qty Int
        )
    Insert into @T
     SELECT 1,1,100001, 100 Union All
     SELECT 1,2,100002, 110 Union All
     SELECT 1,3,100003, 120 Union All
     SELECT 2,1,100004, 130 Union All
     SELECT 2,2,100005, 200 Union All
     SELECT 2,3,100006, 300 Union All
     SELECT 2,4,100007, 400 

    ;with cte1 as
        (
            select *,
            LEAD(Number) OVER(partition by id1 order by id2) as leadingNumber,
            LEAD(Qty) OVER(partition by id1 order by id2) as LeadingQty,

            ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by id1 order by (select null)) as rowNum
             from @T
        )
        ,
    cte2
        As
        (

            select 
            c1.id1,c1.Id2,
            c1.Number As Number1,c1.Qty as Qty1,c1.leadingNumber As Number2, c1.LeadingQty as Qty2
            ,LEAD(leadingNumber) OVER(partition by id1 order by id2)  as Number3,
            LEAD(LeadingQty) OVER(partition by id1 order by id2) as Qty3
            from cte1 c1
        )

    Select Number1,Qty1,Number2,Qty2,Number3,Qty3
    from cte2 where id2%3=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After a few researchs, i found a solution to generate dynamic columns and using `PIVOT` i solved my problem. Thanks to all for the tips.

```
DECLARE  @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),  @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @Param1 AS int

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(number) FROM View_GRTLinhasGRTLinhasTela WHERE id1 = @Param1 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')  

SET @query = 'SELECT *
FROM(
SELECT p.number, p.qty FROM View_GRTLinhasGRTLinhasTela p
WHERE p.id1 = @Param1) AS sourcetable
PIVOT (
SUM(qty) 
FOR number IN (' + @cols + ') ) AS pivottable'

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```